# Django web application deployed on Heroku using Gunicorn - Half of the requests fail randomly (error code 500)

Tags: django, heroku, uwsgi, gunicorn, web-worker

I deployed a Django web application on Heroku using gunicorn wsgi server. Everything works fine in local.

That's my procfile `web: gunicorn traineau.wsgi`

To keep it simple when I push one of the buttons in the app it's supposed to simply do `Prod1=Prod1+1.` in Python and then returns it to JS using 
`return HttpResponse(json.dumps(raw_dict), content_type="application/json")` and display the updated Prod value in the app.

Prod1 is a global variable since I need it in other functions.

When I run my app and click that button a couple times, half the requests I make fail with error code 500 (Internal Server Error) but randomly. ex: 1ok, 3fail, 2ok, 5fail. At the end with a big enough sample it's pretty close the 50% fail.

I know Gunicorn is a prefork worker model and heroku sets per default 2 WEB_CONCURRENCY.
I set the WEB_CONCURRENCY to 1 in the CONFIG_VAR of Heroku and it doesn't help.

If I restart the application a couple times without restarting the dyno, instead of the error code 500, it will eventualy alternate between 2 ranges of values. Example 1-2-3-4-20-21-5-6-7-22-23, etc.
If I restart the dyno, we're back with 50% fails.

I use the free Dyno. I tried to upgrade to Hobby and it didn't change anything.

```
=== web (Free): gunicorn traineau.wsgi (1)
web.1: up 2018/06/06 18:25:08 +0200 (~ 2m ago)
```

Since this application is for only 1 user (for training purposes), would it be better to use Something else then Gunicorn? Would it solve my problem if I use uWSGI for instance?

Comment: The problem is not your server. You really can't do what you are trying to do. Store the data in some kind of datastore - Redis would be ideal, and there are several Redis providers that have a free tier.

Comment: I would still want to understand what is going on behind the scene.. why 50% failed request? @Daniel Roseman the project is linked with a PostgreSQL DB. Do you recommend storing the data there or using Redis (I never used any of them, the simpler the better for now)?

Comment: I increased the number of lines in Heroku logs to check the start of Gunicorn. Found out 2 workers were still booted at the start of the application. I double-checked my WEB_CONCURRENCY variable to realize I wrote WEB_CONCURENCY instead (missing R). Heroku didn't thrown an error, just seemed to ignore the variable. Now it works just the way I want with WEB_CONCURRENCY=1. I'll still include some Redis Cache in my code.. just because it looks like the good practice. This worker thing is still a little bit mysterions to me.. why 1 returned a value and the other one failed systematically?